# Any way to handle plurals in NLP without stemming words

Tags: python, natural-language, text-mining, nltk, information-extraction

I am playing around with topic modeling, and I notice a lot of related plural and singular words in my corpus (e.g. 'champion' and 'champions' are both found).

I gave the porter stemmer in NLTK a shot, but full-on stemming removes a lot of other details that I would like to retain.

Is there a way to depluralize terms using python?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not related to any topic on CV.

Comment: Questions about how to use software (eg, Python) are generally off topic here. A software-neutral text mining question about how to handle stemming issues when you want to preserve other details (what?) might be worthwhile, though.

Comment: (Note that this question would also be off topic on [SO].)

Comment: I figured this would be considered to machine learning, since it is about the transformation of text into features. If this is off topic here and on stack overflow, is there a better place to ask this that you would suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a regex stemming using nltk.stem.regexp.RegexpStemmer.

```
stemmer = RegexpStemmer('s$|ies$')
```

I'm sure this won't cover all the cases you'd like, and there are a lot of nuances with plural words, but you can customize this however you want to adjust for your scenarios.